# How to animate divs position using CSS one by one?

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to make a infinite CSS animation on black circles. If one black circle is animating to top or bottom, others should not be. And if this one animation get again 0% (stop), the next one should start. If animation of the last element stop, the first should start.

Below sample of code that I'm working with, I can't figure out how to stop the animation if other circle is animating.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  background: #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .item {
    animation: mymove 3s infinite;
}
.wrapper .item:nth-child(2) {
    animation: mymove 3s infinite 1s;
}
.wrapper .item:nth-child(3) {
    animation: mymove 3s infinite 2s;
}
.wrapper .item:nth-child(4) {
    animation: mymove 3s infinite 3s;
}
.wrapper .item:nth-child(5) {
    animation: mymove 3s infinite 4s;
}
.wrapper .item:nth-child(6) {
    animation: mymove 3s infinite 5s;
}
@keyframes mymove {
  0%   {top: 0px;}
  50%  {top: -15px;}
  100% {top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>

<div class="item">

</div>
<div class="item">

</div>
<div class="item">

</div>
<div class="item">

</div>
<div class="item">

</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different idea using one element and background. We have 5 radial-gradient placed at different horizontal position ( `calc(x*100%/4)` ) and they all start at the bottom ( `100%` ) then the animation will move them one by one from `100%` (bottom) to `0%` (top)

```css
.wrapper {
  --c:radial-gradient(circle farthest-side, #000 97%,transparent 100%);

  display: flex;
  height:65px; /* this will define the area of movement (bigger than circle sizes) */
  width:350px;
  background:
    var(--c) calc(0*100%/4) 100%, /* circle X Y */
    var(--c) calc(1*100%/4) 100%,
    var(--c) calc(2*100%/4) 100%,
    var(--c) calc(3*100%/4) 100%,
    var(--c) calc(4*100%/4) 100%;
  background-size:50px 50px; /* width height of the circles */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin:10px;
  animation: mymove 5s infinite; 
}

@keyframes mymove {
  0%  {background-position: calc(0*100%/4) 100%, calc(1*100%/4) 100%, calc(2*100%/4) 100%, calc(3*100%/4) 100%, calc(4*100%/4) 100%;}
  10% {background-position: calc(0*100%/4)   0%, calc(1*100%/4) 100%, calc(2*100%/4) 100%, calc(3*100%/4) 100%, calc(4*100%/4) 100%;}
  20% {background-position: calc(0*100%/4) 100%, calc(1*100%/4) 100%, calc(2*100%/4) 100%, calc(3*100%/4) 100%, calc(4*100%/4) 100%;}
  30% {background-position: calc(0*100%/4) 100%, calc(1*100%/4)   0%, calc(2*100%/4) 100%, calc(3*100%/4) 100%, calc(4*100%/4) 100%;}
  40% {background-position: calc(0*100%/4) 100%, calc(1*100%/4) 100%, calc(2*100%/4) 100%, calc(3*100%/4) 100%, calc(4*100%/4) 100%;}
  50% {background-position: calc(0*100%/4) 100%, calc(1*100%/4) 100%, calc(2*100%/4)   0%, calc(3*100%/4) 100%, calc(4*100%/4) 100%;}
  60% {background-position: calc(0*100%/4) 100%, calc(1*100%/4) 100%, calc(2*100%/4) 100%, calc(3*100%/4) 100%, calc(4*100%/4) 100%;}
  70% {background-position: calc(0*100%/4) 100%, calc(1*100%/4) 100%, calc(2*100%/4) 100%, calc(3*100%/4)   0%, calc(4*100%/4) 100%;}
  80% {background-position: calc(0*100%/4) 100%, calc(1*100%/4) 100%, calc(2*100%/4) 100%, calc(3*100%/4) 100%, calc(4*100%/4) 100%;}
  90% {background-position: calc(0*100%/4) 100%, calc(1*100%/4) 100%, calc(2*100%/4) 100%, calc(3*100%/4) 100%, calc(4*100%/4)   0%;}
  100%{background-position: calc(0*100%/4) 100%, calc(1*100%/4) 100%, calc(2*100%/4) 100%, calc(3*100%/4) 100%, calc(4*100%/4) 100%;}
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>

</div>
```

Or you update your code like below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  background: #000;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper .item {
  animation: mymove-1 5s infinite;
}
.wrapper .item:nth-child(2) {animation-name: mymove-2;}
.wrapper .item:nth-child(3) {animation-name: mymove-3;}
.wrapper .item:nth-child(4) {animation-name: mymove-4;}
.wrapper .item:nth-child(5) {animation-name: mymove-5;}

@keyframes mymove-1 {
  0% {top: 0px;}
  10% {top: -15px;}
  20% {top: 0px;}
}
@keyframes mymove-2 {
  20% {top: 0px;}
  30% {top: -15px;}
  40% {top: 0px;}
}
@keyframes mymove-3 {
  40% {top: 0px;}
  50% {top: -15px;}
  60% {top: 0px;}
}
@keyframes mymove-4 {
  60% {top: 0px;}
  70% {top: -15px;}
  80% {top: 0px;}
}
@keyframes mymove-5 {
  80% {top: 0px;}
  90% {top: -15px;}
  100%{top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>

  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>
  <div class="item">

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It is a very nice idea but in my case i can't use it. In my websites my circles are assigned to a specific content and can't be animated using background, they can be only animated using their position.

Comment: @matep05 check the update, added another idea

Comment: The update version will be helpful for my project, thanks a lot.

Additional: Is it possible to stop animation for all circles except the one which is hover?

Comment: @matep05 this requires more work. I advise you to consider another question for this since it's out of the scope here and you will get better help with a new question